# Is it OK to read Qt Widgets from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I found many answers say that accessing Qt Gui Widgets from another thread is not safe. I agree with this if we try to modify the widgets. But what if I only read the value of widget, without any modification?
I have designed a GUI tool using Qt, and my working thread reads Widgets directly, for example, get the text of QLineEdit, get the value of QComboBox,etc. And I haven't found any problem.
I pass the pointer of MainWindow to working thread. 
Is this really not safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: It is always a bad idea to read properties from another thread without protecting the memory ([Mutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html), [Signal & Slot](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)).

Your situation: If nothing wants to change the value, you should be fine. There are no problems if every thread only reads the value. But if you change the value of the QComboBox (for example) by clicking **arrow up**, **arrow down** or **selecting a new item** (what I expect you will do, because that's the reason of using a [QComboBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html)) the value will be written and then the application **can** crash if your worker thread wants to read the value in the exact same moment (the possibility of a carsh depends on the frequenz your thread pulls the informations).

Your application never crashed because the condition never appeared. 
But that does not mean that this can not happen.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.